# Determinate song's tempo using ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg

I found ffmpeg library pretty good for converting from mp3 to wav.
I'm using this library to convert:

https://github.com/WritingMinds/ffmpeg-android-java

Then I want to do this steps:

- determinate songs tempo
- convert it into wav
- slice the song into segments according to bpm: 
  for example per bar or per 1/2 note.

I haven't found any command that I can determinate bpm.
Maybe you guys know if ffmpeg can actually do it, or advice another library that can handle this problem

Comment: You need to get more than a single bpm value in order to describe all the beats in a song; you need to know the timing of every single beat. Tempos created by humans tend to "wander" slightly over the course of a song. ...And I'm no ffmpeg expert, but no -- it can't do that.

Comment: Maybe I can do some frequency analysis using FFT and then slice the beats according to high energy levels. I think that's how tempo is detected

Comment: Some googling led me to [this](http://mziccard.me/2015/05/28/beats-detection-algorithms-1/). Skimmed it; looks good.

Comment: use this js ...https://killercrush.github.io/music-tempo/example/example-advanced.html

Answer (score 1):

I've been using [Aubio](https://aubio.org/) to do this. From the website:

> Features
>
> aubio currently provides the following features:
>
> - digital filters
> - phase vocoder
> - onset detection (several methods)
> - pitch tracking (several methods)
> - beat and tempo tracking
> - mel frequency cepstrum coefficients (MFCC)
> - transient / steady-state separation

[GitHub project](https://github.com/aubio/aubio).